# How to get the quotient and remainder of division

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, division, modulo

I have one `employee` table which contains:

```
emp id      Sum
------      ---
1            7
2            6
```

I want a SQL query for getting the quotient and remainder when dividing the `Sum` with 8.

Comment: This still sounds like a valid question.

Answer (score 25):

Use [integer division](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) and [mod](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod) operators to get the quotient and remainder:

```sql
SELECT
    sum, 
    sum / 8 AS result,
    sum div 8 AS quotient,
    sum mod 8 AS remainder
FROM employee
```

Sample output:

```
sum | result | quotient | remainder
7   | 0.8750 | 0        | 7
6   | 0.7500 | 0        | 6
9   | 1.1250 | 1        | 1
10  | 1.2500 | 1        | 2
11  | 1.3750 | 1        | 3
12  | 1.5000 | 1        | 4
13  | 1.6250 | 1        | 5
14  | 1.7500 | 1        | 6
15  | 1.8750 | 1        | 7
16  | 2.0000 | 2        | 0
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `%` operator to get the remainder. Here's an example.

```
SELECT Round(17 / 4) -- quotient without decimal   
SELECT 17 % 4 -- remainder
```

Answer (score 3):

What will be the return type of your qoutient? If you don't care if its a floating point or an integer(whole number). You can try this.

```
 SELECT 
       (sum / 8) AS qoutient, 
       (sum % 8) AS reminder 
  FROM employee
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the mysql function DIV to get the qoutient
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) :

```
SELECT 14 DIV 3
```

will return 4

It should do the trick

As for the remainder, others have replied

Answer (score 1):

For my PL/SQL function I usually use:

```
 SELECT trunc(sum/8) --- Quotient
 SELECT mod(sum/8) -- Remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

use floor function, select floor(column_name/divisor) from dual